# Basic questions about the axiom of regularity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Axiom of regularity prevents an infinite descending sequence of sets but not an ascending one. Why is the first considered "bad", so that it has to be banished, and the second one is not? And how about a finite descending sequence? Is it forbidden as well?

Comment: Finite descending sequences are OK. Note that any infinite increasing sequence includes arbitrarily long finite increasing sequences; reading those in reverse order, you get long finite descending sequences.  As for why people like me want the axiom of regularity, see my answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/219647/6794 on MathOverflow.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I understood, infinite descending sequences have to be banned because they lack a minimal element, which means, they're not well-founded. But why a minimal element is considered necessary in a regular set?

Comment: Look at the next-to-last paragraph of my old answer, especially the sentence in parentheses.